# Ссылки на activity и утечки памяти

Tags: android

Есть активити. В нём есть разные блоки (например, некая форма из нескольки полей). Хочется поведение этих блоков вынести в отдельные классы.

- Создаю класс, скажем, `MyBlock`
- В `onCreate()` активити создаю объект, передавая ему:

  - ViewGroup - контейнер блока
  - Ссылку на само активити - нужна для проброса событий и context для создания новых элементов внутри
  - Объект ещё вешает на элементы обработчики для onClick и другие
- Сохраняю ссылку на объект в свойстве объекта activity - нужна для взаимодействия с ним
- И таких свойств может быть несколько, включая списки однотипных объектов

Вопрос: как тут обстоит дело с утечками памяти?

Активити может часто уничтожаться/пересоздаваться. Советуют "не держать ссылку на активити в объектах, которые живут дольше этого активити". В моём примере они жить дольше не должны. Однако, тут образуется множество циклических ссылок. Сможет ли сборщик мусора их корректно разрулить?

Стоит ли (и поможет ли) в `activity.onDestroy()` дестроить все связанные объекты и обнулять ссылки на них?

Comment: onDestroy не всегда вызывается. Сможет если все ссылки в пределах видимости данной активности.